# Provided seeds do not result in a valid address

Tags: pda, cpi, mint, client

Here is my initialize instruction:

```
pub fn initialize(
    ctx: Context<Initialize>,
    token_name: String,
    token_symbol: String,
    token_uri: String,
) -> Result<()> {
    // PDA seeds and bump to "sign" for CPI
    let seeds = &["mint_account".as_bytes()];
    let (_, bump) = Pubkey::find_program_address(seeds, &ctx.accounts.mint_account.key());
    let signer = &[&seeds[..], &[&[bump]]];

    let data_v2 = DataV2 {
        name: token_name,
        symbol: token_symbol,
        uri: token_uri,
        seller_fee_basis_points: 0,
        creators: None,
        collection: None,
        uses: None,
    };

    let cpi_ctx = CpiContext::new_with_signer(
        ctx.accounts.token_metadata_program.to_account_info(),
        CreateMetadataAccountsV3 {
            metadata: ctx.accounts.metadata_account.to_account_info(),
            mint: ctx.accounts.mint_account.to_account_info(),
            mint_authority: ctx.accounts.mint_account.to_account_info(),
            update_authority: ctx.accounts.mint_account.to_account_info(),
            payer: ctx.accounts.admin.to_account_info(),
            system_program: ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
            rent: ctx.accounts.rent.to_account_info(),
        },
        signer,
    );

    create_metadata_accounts_v3(
        cpi_ctx,
        data_v2,
        true,
        true,
        None,
    )?;
    Ok(())
```

Here is my Initialize:

```
 #[derive(Accounts)]
 pub struct Initialize<'info> {
    #[account(
        mut,
        address = ADMIN_PUBKEY
    )]
    pub admin: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(
        init,
        seeds = [b"mint_account"],
        bump,
        payer = admin,
        mint::decimals = 9,
        mint::authority = mint_account,
        mint::freeze_authority = mint_account,
    )]
    pub mint_account: Account<'info, Mint>,

    #[account(
        init_if_needed,
        seeds = [b"fee_collector"],
        bump,
        payer = admin,
        space = 8
    )]
    pub fee_collector: Account<'info, VaultAccount>,

    /// CHECK: Address validated using constraint
    #[account(
        mut,
        address=MplMetadata::find_pda(&mint_account.key()).0
    )]
    pub metadata_account: UncheckedAccount<'info>,

    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
    pub token_metadata_program: Program<'info, Metadata>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
    pub rent: Sysvar<'info, Rent>,
```

Here is my client code (test):

```
describe("test", () => {
  const provider = anchor.AnchorProvider.env();
  anchor.setProvider(provider);
  const payer = provider.wallet as anchor.Wallet;

  const program = anchor.workspace.Test as anchor.Program<Test>;

  const TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM_ID = new PublicKey(
      "metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s"
  );

  const metaplex = Metaplex.make(provider.connection);

  const [mintPDA] = anchor.web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
    [Buffer.from("mint_account")],
    program.programId
  );


  it("Initializes", async () => {
    const balance = await provider.connection.getBalance(payer.publicKey);
    console.log(`Payer's balance: ${balance}`);

    const mintMetadataPDA = await metaplex
      .nfts()
      .pdas()
      .metadata({ mint: mintPDA });

    const txHash = await program.methods
      .initialize()
      .accounts({
        epochState: epochStatePDA,
        mintAccount: mintPDA,
        feeCollector: feeCollectorPDA,
        metadataAccount: mintMetadataPDA,
        tokenMetadataProgram: TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM_ID,
      }).signers([payer.payer])
      .rpc({
        skipPreflight: true,
      });
```

It crashes, here are the logs:

```
 logs: 
   [ 'Program 48wChQQ9VHnVpWVkm8HzsckwF1mqHdGpH3Mz9nHsn41P invoke [1]',
     'Program log: Instruction: Initialize',
     'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [2]',
     'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success',
     'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [2]',
     'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success',
     'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [2]',
     'Program log: Instruction: InitializeMint2',
     'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 2828 of 184882 compute units',
     'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success',
     'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [2]',
     'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success',
     'Program 48wChQQ9VHnVpWVkm8HzsckwF1mqHdGpH3Mz9nHsn41P consumed 35243 of 200000 compute units',
     'Program 48wChQQ9VHnVpWVkm8HzsckwF1mqHdGpH3Mz9nHsn41P failed: Could not create program address with signer seeds: Provided seeds do not result in a valid address' ],
  programErrorStack: { stack: [ [Object] ] } }
```

I don't know why this happens, does anybody have any idea? Seems like cookbook and docs are outdated and are not aligned between examples.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without having much detail on your program goal, I can see some "issues".

1 - let (_, bump) = Pubkey::**find_program_address**(seeds, &ctx.accounts.**mint_account**.**key**());

The **find_program_address** method expects the second argument to be a programID, and you're passing your mint_account key as programID. Also, as a tip, if you're using anchor 0.29 you can always access the canonical bumps that anchor found by using "ctx.bumps.account_name", in this case it would be **let bump = ctx.bumps.mint_account;**

Try changing your the way you create your seeds to something like this: **let seeds = &[&b"mint_account"[..], &[bump]]; let signer_seeds = &[&seeds[..]];** And use that signer_seeds variable as signer in your CPI context

2 - You're initializing a mint account that is his own mint authority.
I'm guessing that what you're actually trying to do is to create a PDA that will be the mint authority of your mint account.. Am I correct?
If so, I would suggest that you pass the PDA account in your context, and add that as mint authority of your mint account

Check if that solve your problem, and let me know

Comment: "what you're actually trying to do is to create a PDA that will be the mint authority of your mint account" -yes, exactly. I need to make my program be the authority for mint account.

Comment: how do i make my program mint authority? or do you mean that I have to create an empy pda for minting authority?

Comment: here (https://solanacookbook.com/gaming/interact-with-tokens.html#create-mint-instruction) i see that "// The PDA is both the address of the mint account and the mint authority"

Comment: You can do it, it was more a suggestion so you could have an auth PDA to use later as auth for any other operations.
Looking deeply into your code, try changing your the way you create your seeds to something like this:
let seeds = &[&b"mint_account"[..], &[bump]];
let signer_seeds = &[&seeds[..]];

And use those signer_seeds variable as signer in your CPI context. I will update my answer accordingly

Comment: that helped, now i have my test passing. Thanks a lot for help @ASCorreia

Comment: but if I try to run it again im getting: Raw transaction 5qCdjNKnGVC4GEkiUALw7YJKwwz2taBHPj91tWxbStmWrQZmaoQDwycwVkd4iZnCNbTFkcQdYDsuaRZHY2GEtqZX failed ({"err":{"InstructionError":[0,{"Custom":0}]}})
Is this because it's already initialized? I guess yes, as it is first custom error.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.. most likely you're trying to init an account that is already initialized. If the answer solved your issue, please accept it so that it can help other devs that might face the same issue